# Which lightweight python web framework has applications and hot-deployed code

Tags: python

I am used to PHP having applications. For example,

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\app1
c:\xampp\htdocs\app2
```

can be accessed as

```
localhost://app1/page.php
localhost://app2/page.php
```

Things to be noticed:

1. a directory placed inside the www-root directory maps directly with the URL
2. when a file/directory is added/removed/changed, the **worker processes seamlessly reflect** that change (new files are hot-deployed).

---

I am on the lookout for a **mature python web framework**. Its for a web API which will be deployed for multiple clients, and each copy will diverge on customization. And our workflow has frequent interaction/revision cycles between us and our clients. Hence the "drag and drop" deployment is a must.

Which python framework enables this? I prefer a lightweight solution (which doesnt impose MVC, ORMs etc)

---

Related

[How to build Twisted servers which are able to do hot code swap in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864380/how-to-build-twisted-servers-which-are-able-to-do-hot-code-swap-in-python)

[Python web hosting: Why are server restarts necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711483/python-web-hosting-why-are-server-restarts-necessary)

[fastcgi, cherrypy, and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947344/fastcgi-cherrypy-and-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No mature python framework that I'm aware of allows you to map urls to python modules, and frankly, for good reason. You can do this with CGI, but it's definitely not the recommended way to deploy python apps. Setting that requirement aside, [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) are both lightweight micro web-frameworks with similar approaches, both allow you to reload automatically when changes are detected (this is only wise during development).

Answer (score 2):

There is no web framework in Python that I know of that lets you do that out of the box, but if you need it it's not to hard to add with a bit of `convention over configuration`.

Simply pick your web framework of choice in Python and then write a wrapper to the main application that walks a directory or set of directory and auto-registers routes from the modules inside of them.  Have your modules do the same thing in their `__init__.py` files to the other files located with them.  Then just set up your WSGI code to autoreload when the WSGI script is updated and your deployment during development simply becomes a two step process - add file then touch `dev_app.wsgi`.  You could even add a *real* deployment option to this wrapper that walks a set up *dev* environment like this and generates hard-coded URL-to-function mappings for deployment.

However, all of this work isn't really necessary.  Python is not PHP and the way you develop in one doesn't necessarily translate to the other well.  If the client wants variable routes, use dynamic routes and give them (or you) an admin interface to control the mapping of content to URL.  Use flat files, SQLite, a NoSQL datastore, or the ether to store these mappings and the content.  Use a template engine like Jinja2, Mako, Cheetah or Genshi to maintain your general layout.  Wrap this all up with an object oriented structure to make extending it easy (or use a functional paradigm if that comes more naturally to you). **Or**, drop the whole dynamic in production portion and generate flat HTML files a la Jekyll.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers. But I am actually inspired to hack together something that you mentioned in paragraph 1.

Answer (score 1):

CherryPy is a mature web framework that redeploys automatically when changes are detected. The file structure - URL isn't there, but it is a lightweight framework that doesn't impose ORM, MVC, or even a templating engine.

Answer (score -1):

If you are used to PHP, you might want to take a look at the Apache modules [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/) or [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) (and [WSGI](http://www.wsgi.org/) in general if you do web development -- which is the Pythonic way).

With those two modules, the Python interpreter gets started every time a request comes in (similar to PHP). Needless to say, this slows things down but you'll always get the result based on your newest code. Depending on your expected traffic numbers, this might or might not be okay for you.

BUT: If you decide to write your own framework, you most probably do **not** want to write a system that supports "hot-deploying". Even though the `reload()` command is built-in, it takes more than just that and will get you into a world full of pain.

Comment: Don't use mod_python as it is no longer maintained or developed. And in neither mod_python or mod_wsgi does the Python interpreter get started on every request, it stays persistent in memory along with the already loaded code. Thus code changes are not picked up on every request.

Comment: "Python interpreter get started on every request" that would be the CGI way.